# AWK parse CSV, extract substring from cell and add new column with extracted value

Tags: csv, awk

AWK parse CSV, extract substring from cell and add new column. Where there is no matching pattern (i.e. no substring to extract), add blank cell to CSV.

---

**Source Data (3 example columns, actual data is 20+ columns)**

```
"col1txtA","col2txtA","TYPE=ARRAY&ID=111&OPERATINGSYSTEM=WINDOWS%2010&DATE=0000"
"col1txtB","col2txtB","TYPE=ARRAY&ID=112&DATE=0000"
```

**Attempted code**

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
  NR>1
  {$4=match($3,/OPERATINGSYSTEM=[^&]*/)}
  1'
```

**Desired output data (new column even if blank result)**

```
"col1txtA","col2txtA","TYPE=ARRAY&ID=111&OPERATINGSYSTEM=WINDOWS%2010&DATE=0000","WINDOWS%2010"
"col1txtB","col2txtB","TYPE=ARRAY&ID=112&DATE=0000",""
```

Comment: Can any of your double-quoted fields contain commas, newlines or escaped double quotes?

Comment: @EdMorton yes it is possible the values may contain commas, they won't have new lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `awk`:

You can save the result of your match in an array `a` and access the element that was matched inside the parentheses of your the regex as `a[1]`. The array argument is a gawk extension.

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '
{
  if (match($3, /OPERATINGSYSTEM=([^&]*)/, a)){
    $(NF+1)="\"" a[1] "\""
  }
  else {
    $(NF+1)="\"\""
  }
}
1' input.csv
```

Comment: confirm solution works with GNU AWK (GAWK). Can the ELSE IF be amended to check if header row / first line of file, print OPERATINGSYSTEM?

Comment: Unforeseen error when running on entire dataset. Sometimes the OPERATINGSYSTEM= is the last of the string and the matched value stored to the array contains the closing `"` quotation mark - which then corrupts the CSV file.